# Tooltip don't appear any more

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

Yesterday my bootstrap tooltip was ok, everything worked fine but today, after I added this code into the header.php :

```
<!doctype html>  

<!--[if IEMobile 7 ]> <html <?php language_attributes(); ?>class="no-js iem7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|(gt IEMobile 7)|!(IEMobile)|!(IE)]><!--><html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
```

my tooltip show no more. I tried to delete this code, buckup the file in the hosting, delete every changes I did in css last time - nothing worked. I'm so upset. What it might be?

My wordpress site:  http://video-walks.ru.com/?page_id=315.  My header.php :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <head>
   <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
    <title><?php wp_title('|',true,'right'); ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

  <?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>



<!-- tooltip enables -->
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>


 <script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
              $(document).ready(function () {
                $("a").tooltip({
                  'selector': '',
                  'placement': 'bottom'
                });
                console.log("jimmy");
              });

            </script>



<script type="text/javascript">
              $(document).ready(function () {
                $("span").tooltip({
                  'selector': '',
                  'placement': 'bottom'
                });
                console.log("jimmy");
              });

            </script>


    <?php wp_head(); ?>
  </head>
  <body >

  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="brand"  href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>"><li class="icon-home"> </li><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav">

             <?php wp_list_pages(array('title_li' => '', 'exclude' => 310)); ?>

          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">

<?php if (! is_front_page()) : ?>


<form action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" method="get" class="form-stacked pull-right">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="center">
            <div class="input-append input-prepend">
                  <input type="text" name="s"  id="search" placeholder="<?php _e("Search","bonestheme"); ?>" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" /><button type="submit" class="btn  btn-inverse"><i class="icon-search"></i> </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>

 <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that twitter has moved the tooltip script and it is not available for your site.
If you can afford the traffic, you can serve it locally:

1. Download [twitter bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/zipball/master).
2. Extract `twbs-bootstrap-<somebuild>/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js` to some directory on your server (that is serverd, of course).
3. Change the line `<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>` to point to where you put the script.

This should probably solve your problem for the time being. You can search for a CDN that will provide a reliable URL for that file as a long-term solution.

Comment: Thank you, though I did like you said, this don't work                         <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>  or the path is wrong, though I tried every possible paths

Comment: Where did you extract the file to? It should be located within WordPress's directory.

Comment: Where? in the wp-includes/js ?

Comment: This is a reasonable location.

Comment: What is the local file path?

Comment: I don't know, file of my theme is bootwalks, or something else?

Comment: Within my theme I have the file js too

Comment: It seems to be bootwalks. You can put it there or somewhere else that is appropriate. It has little meaning. It is more important that you know where you put it and specify that path in the `php` file.

Comment: Change the line to `<script src="/wp-content/themes/bootwalks/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>`.

Comment: Yeaaaaaaaaa! I got it!!!!!!!!! <script src="/wp-includes/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script> Thank you soooo much!

Comment: You are very welcome. Now find yourself a good web technologies book and a comfortable seat.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I changed everything to <script src="/wp-content/themes/bootwalks/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>   that's better!